# Удаление картинки из папки после её удаления из таблицы по внешнему ключу

Tags: php, mysql, sql, node.js

Создаю таблицу `product` и задаю внешний ключ с таблицей user

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

После удаления строки  user удаляются все связанные с ней строки из таблицы `product`
Вопрос возможно ли в серверном языке програмирования предпочтительно node.js
как-то отследить удаление строки из таблицы `product` (поставить какой-то слушатель) после чего внутри этого слушателя удалить картинку из папки?

Comment: Картинка связана с пользователем или с записями  из таблицы `product`, которые каскадно удаляются?

Comment: Картинка связана с записями из таблицы product, которые каскадно удаляются

Comment: Тогда перед удалением вы должны получить id-ки, пути к картинкам или что у вас там хранится в `product` и только затем удалять запись из сущности `user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае правильнее удаление строки из таблицы обернуть в метод, который бы уже задавал логику удаления картинок. Также необходимо исключить возможность удаления строк из данной таблицы минуя данный метод.